# Trouble with php 'if exists' syntax

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create an if statement for the nbsp (space).

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); echo '&nbsp;'; ?>
```

This is at the front of a line:

```
<h2><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); echo '&nbsp;'; ?>Example
```

If the term exists, then it'll show 'Term Example'. If not, I need to show 'Example'. But right now, without an if, I get ' Example'. Note the ugly space.

I think I'd done this before, using this:

```
<?php if (post_custom('the_term')) {
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); echo '&nbsp;';
} else {
echo '';
?>
```

... but it's not working. Server error.

I also tried this:

```
<?php $the_term_check = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true);
if (!empty($the_term_check))
echo '<h2>'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); echo ' Example'</h2>';
if (empty($the_term_check))
echo'<h2>Example</h2>';
?>
```

Still not it. This one echos 'Example' twice -- and one of them doesn't even have the right HTML markup.

Either plain PHP or WordPress-specific code would work, as this is pulling the custom meta from a custom post type -- if it exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: For one thing, you are missing a closing brace for `else {
echo '';` - Then this `echo ' Example'</h2>'` one quote too many.

Comment: Oh good grief --- that's all it was. That's what I get for working when I'm so tired that my eyes are going blurry. That first code block did the trick. Time to get off the computer, methinks! Thanks for the easy quick assist.

Comment: @fred make that an answer please

Comment: @Dez  Done, as per your request. *Cheers*

Comment: This question seems to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as the problem was a **a simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace for `else { echo '';`

Then this `echo ' Example'</h2>'` there is one quote too many after "Example".

Rewrites

```
<?php if (post_custom('the_term')) {
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); echo '&nbsp;';
} else {
echo '';
} // added missing brace
?>
```

and

```
<?php $the_term_check = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true);
if (!empty($the_term_check))
echo '<h2>'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); echo ' Example</h2>';
if (empty($the_term_check))
echo'<h2>Example</h2>';
?>
```

or as, and with added braces (it's good practice)

```
<?php 
$the_term_check = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true);
    if (!empty($the_term_check)){
       echo '<h2>'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true); 
       echo ' Example</h2>';
}
    if (empty($the_term_check)){
       echo'<h2>Example</h2>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you.

```
<h2><?php echo !empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true)[0]) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_term', true)[0]."&nbsp;" : ""; ?>Example</h2>
```